# $f^{-1}[B]$ where $B = [-1 ; 3] \times [1;5]$ and $f(x) = ( |x| , (|x|-1)^2) $. Did I do it right?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

There is a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as:
$$f(x) = ( |x| , (|x|-1)^2 ) $$

find $f^{-1}[B]$ where $B = [-1 ; 3] \times [1;5]$.

From first part of the function I get that:

- $|x| \in [-1 ; 3] \implies |x| \in [0 ; 3] \implies x \in [-3 ; 3]$

From the second part:

- $(|x|-1)^2 \in [1;5] \implies x \in (-1 - \sqrt{5} ; -2) \cup (2; 1 + \sqrt{5})$

Finaly:
$[-3 ; 3]\cap((-1 - \sqrt{5} ; -2) \cup (2; 1 + \sqrt{5})) = [-3 ; -2] \cup [2;3] $

Therefore:
$f^{-1}[B] = [-3 ; -2] \cup [2;3] $

Is that correct?

Comment: I changed $\langle \cdot ; \cdot \rangle$ into $( \cdot,\cdot)$ in order to avoid confusion with inner product. Let me know if I misinterpreted what your question is.

Comment: No, that's fine. Thank you